# Generate <li> with custom class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, class

I am looking for a solution to do the following:

I have two links in a list:

```
<ul>
     <li class="1"><a>Option #1</a><li>
     <li class="2"><a>Option #2</a><li>
</ul>
```

When I click on a link, I want class to change to "selected", for example, I clicked "Option #1":

```
<ul>
     <li class="1 selected"><a>Option #1</a><li>
     <li class="2"><a>Option #2</a><li>
</ul>
```

The solution in jQuery is not necessary, but I guess jQuery is the right tool to do this?

Kindly help.

Comment: What should happen when you click "Option #2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('li').removeClass('selected');
});
```

You also need to close `<li>` using `</li>` instead of `<li>` to make your HTML markup valid.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ghm4k978/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) functions, or if you want to save you some time the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)